# Delete Everything Inside Root Directory / while keeping /home Directory intact

Tags: ubuntu, home

I have two partitions with **two kubuntu's**, one in **/dev/sda1** along with home directory and other in **/dev/sda2**(able to access /home in **sda1** via mounting). I wish to remove kubuntu in /dev/sda1 while keeping /home intact, so that only **/dev/sda2** boots still able to access /home(leftover of /dev/sda1).

Comment: What have you tried so far? In terms of permissions, there is nothing special about the directories (as seen from an inactive system). You can remove them as usual.

Comment: Run midnight commander or any file manager with sudo and delete what you need

Answer (score 0):

```bash
if cd /mnt/sda1; then
    echo -n "Do you want to delete: `ls | grep -v home`? (y/n)"
    read answer
    test "$answer" = "y" -o "$answer" = "Y" && sudo rm -rf `ls | grep -v home`
fi
```

Totally untested, exercise extreme caution.